# Creating and Storing Multi-Dimensional Array in a netCDF File

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, netcdf

This question has potentially two parts but maybe only one if the first part can be encapsulated by the second. I am using python with numpy and netCDF4

First:

I have four lists of different variable values (hereafter referred to elevation values) each of which has a length of 28. These four lists are one set of 5 different latitude values of which are one set of the 24 different time values.

So 24 times...each time with 5 latitudes...each latitude with four lists...each list with 28 values.

I want to create an array with the following dimensions (elevation, latitude, time, variable)

In words, I want to be able to specify which of the four lists I access,which index in the list, and specify a specific time and latitude. So an index into this array would look like this:

array(0,1,2,3) where 0 specifies the first index of the the 4th list specified by the 3. 1 specifies the 2nd latitude, and 2 specifies the 3rd time and the output is the value at that point.

I won't include my code for this part since literally the only things of mention are the lists

list1=[...]

list2=[...]

list3=[...]

list4=[...]

How can I do this, is there an easier structure of the array, or is there anything else I a missing?

Second:

I have created a netCDF file with variables with these four dimensions. I need to set those variables to the array structure made above. I have no idea how to do this and the netCDF4 documentation does a 1-d array in a fairly cryptic way. If the arrays can be made directly into the netCDF file bypassing the need to use numpy first, by all means show me how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After talking to a few people where I work we came up with this solution:

First we made an array of zeroes using the following argument:

array1=np.zeros((28,5,24,4))

Then appended this array by specifying where in the array we wanted to change:

array1[:,0,0,0]=list1

This inserted the values of the list into the first entry in the array.

Next to write the array to a netCDF file, I created a netCDF in the same program I made the array, made a single variable and gave it values like this:

netcdfvariable[:]=array1

Hope that helps anyone who finds this.